# Is it possible to hatch chicks on the XBox?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

In the PC version of Minecraft you can hatch chicks by throwing eggs, which has a 1/8th chance of producing a chick.  I don't want to waste the eggs I already have, but can you produce chicks in the XBox version?

Answer (score 6):

The Xbox version of Minecraft is equivalent to the Beta 1.6.6 version of Minecraft for the PC, and Chicken Eggs have been throwable since Beta 1.0. As it additionally isn't noted in the [differences from PC edition section of the Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Xbox_360_Edition#Differences_from_PC_edition), I don't see a reason why chickens wouldn't be able to hatch from eggs. Also, the [Minecraft: Xbox 360 Edition Wiki page on chickens](http://minecraft360.wikia.com/wiki/Chicken) also states that they can be hatched from eggs. (Note that since baby animals were introduced in the Beta 1.9 Prerelease, adult chickens will spawn from the eggs, and not baby chickens.)

Comment: They'll be adult chickens; baby animals were added much later.

Comment: Right, I forgot about that.

Answer (score 4):

As of Tuesday, October 17th, it's possible to have a chicken farm. In fact, I did one myself yesterday, each egg thrown with Use/Left Trigger (in the 360 version) has a 1/32 chance to hatch.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible, and works in Minecraft XBox 360 edition.

[Here is a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWPbsFnGkB8) showing the throwing of chicken eggs and their hatching into chickens.

Unfortunately, at this time critters are not permanent in the XBox version, so they tend to despawn a lot, so a real chicken farm or egg farm will not work like it does in th ePC version.

Also, breeding is not yet live in the XBox version, so you will get adult chickens from eggs. But you can indeed get them from eggs.

Answer (score 1):

I guess maybe there has been an update since these previous posts. You can make 2 adult chickens enter love mode on the Xbox version by feeding them wheat seeds. They then pop out a baby chick. Save your eggs for something more worthwhile.

Answer (score -1):

well just to make this quick you would see an adult chicken laying an egg pick up the egg throw it on the floor or in the air and it fall to the ground and you have a small chance of a baby chick hatching from the egg and if you want adult chickens put seed in your hand and all chicks that see it will start following you straight away it is a great tip because chicks and adult chickens usually run away.